# Is there a way to change the shape of an AppBar in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have an app bar in my app that has a "floating" look to it. I drew up a simple picture to show what I mean.[simple drawing of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyBg7.jpg)

Is there a way to do this with the new material theming? Thanks.

Comment: you can create your own and set theme with no action bar .. what happens then will be that your app will have no defaultr action bar so you can create your own using any layout and for its height matching action bar height you can pass attr/actionbarheight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, you do have a support action bar already.

You can change its shape by adding a background shape to the file: `drawable/rounded_corners.xml`, which should contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle" >
  <solid android:color="#ff0000cc" />
  <corners android:radius="10dp" /> 
</shape>
```

This file describes a rectangular shape with rounded corners to use as a background.

Then you set that background to your appbar in the onCreate method, for example.

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.rounded_corners));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. would this also work with a bottom app bar and a bottom navigation? I wanted to do a similar thing with those as well and if this worked it would be great.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a way to make the rectangle not go clear to the border of the screen. Thanks.

Comment: In you main.xml file, where you describe ther properties of the Toolbar, you can put it into a  framelayout, example: <FrameLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:padding="10dp"> ... Toolbar ... </FrameLayout>

Comment: ahh thank you. I was attempting to change the width of the bar itself. that did not go well.